# Prove that in an ordered integral domain $x^2 + e = 0$ has no solution.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

To proof I said,
Let $A$ be an ordered integral domain.
Let $x\in A$ such that $x^2+e=0$.
Then $x^2=-e$.
Then $x\neq0$ would imply that $x^2\in A^+$ where $A^+$ is all positive elements of A and would imply that $-e,e\in A^+$.
Thus, $-e+e=0$ would be an element of $A^+$ and would be a contradiction because $0\notin A^+$.
Therefore, $x^2+e=0$ has no solution in an ordered integral domain.

I was wondering if this is a okay proof or what I could improve on. Thank you.

Comment: Why would $e\in A^+$?  Do you mean $e=1$?

Comment: Yep.  Your proof is basically it.  But... let me ask. Have you proven yet that for any $a\in A$ then $a^2 \ge 0$?  And have you proven that if $a > 0$ then $-a <0$ (and vice versa; if $a < 0$ then $-a > 0$)?  ANd have you proven yet that $e >0$.... If you have proven those, your proof is complete and utterly correct.  If you haven't proven those... well you must prove them first.

Comment: @user10354138  I am assuming that $e$ is the multiplicative identity.  That is fairly standard notation.

Answer (score 1):

You proof is good but you are making a few assumptions that must be proven.

You are assuming that if $a \ne 0$ then $a^2 > 0$.  That is true but in is not axiomatic and must be proven.

You are assuming that $e \in A^+$.  That is true but again is not axiomatic and must be proven.

And you are assuming $-e,e \in \mathbb A^+$ is a contradiction?  Why is that?  You seem to be applying that if $a > 0, b > 0$ then $a+b > 0$?  Is that true?  (Yes, it is... although maybe I'm not sure what definition of $a > 0$ is that you are working with... that could be on me.)

But yes... your proof *is* correct and if we can show $a^2 > 0$ when $a \ne 0$ and that $e\in A^{-a}$ and $a, -a \in A^+$ is always a contradiction then your proof is complete.